# How to email with table from template in python?

Tags: python, google-apps-script

I have this code in google script to create an email with a table from the template, but I have to write the same in python.

What can I use to replace "createTemplateFromFile" and to create my table with a loop in python?

Code.gs

```
var htmlTemplate = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("EmailTemplate");
const headers = ws.getRange("A1:L1").getDisplayValues();
htmlTemplate.Col_1 = headers[0][0];
htmlTemplate.Col_2 = headers[0][1]
...
htmlTemplate.Col_11 = headers[0][11]
htmlTemplate.Menssage = menssage
htmlTemplate.tableRangeValues = tableRangeValues
var htmlEmail = htmlTemplate.evaluate().getContent()
```

EmailTemplate.html

```
          <tbody>
         <? tableRangeValues.forEach(r => { ?>  
          <tr style="border-collapse:collapse; border:1px solid #000000" >
            <td style="border-collapse:collapse; border:1px solid #000000" ><?= r[0] ?></td>
            <td style="border-collapse:collapse; border:1px solid #000000"><?= r[1] ?></td>
            <td style="border-collapse:collapse; border:1px solid #000000"><?= r[2] ?></td>
            <td style="border-collapse:collapse; border:1px solid #000000"><?= r[3] ?></td>
            <td style="border-collapse:collapse; border:1px solid #000000"><?= r[4] ?></td>
            <td style="border-collapse:collapse; border:1px solid #000000"><?= r[5] ?></td>
            <td style="border-collapse:collapse; border:1px solid #000000"><?= r[6] ?></td>
            <td style="border-collapse:collapse; border:1px solid #000000"><?= r[7] ?></td>
            <td style="border-collapse:collapse; border:1px solid #000000"><?= r[8] ?></td>
            <td style="border-collapse:collapse; border:1px solid #000000"><?= r[10] ?></td>
            <td style="border-collapse:collapse; border:1px solid #000000"><?= r[11] ?></td>
          </tr>
         <?})?>
      </tbody>
```

Comment: I think the flask module (in python)  render_template() function should do the trick.

Comment: @ThunderCoder good direction but it could need only template `jinja2` from `flask`

Comment: @furas but then how would you get the view?

Comment: @ThunderCoder see my answer below.  I use `jinja` to generate expected `HTML` . OP doesn't use `Flask` and he doesn't need to send this HTML to browser - so he doesn't need `view` - but he want to send it in email.

Comment: @furas, and will an email be able to understand the jinja syntax.

Comment: @ThunderCoder email doesn't have to understand jinja. I use `jinja` to generate pure HTML before sending email and later email will send only pure HTML without jinja syntax. BTW: `flask` makes the same - first it uses `jinja` to generate pure HTML and later it sends pure HTML to browser, not HTML with jinja syntax.

Comment: @ThunderCoder  In `flask` you can even see this pure HTML with `html = render_template(...)`, `print(html)` , `return html`.

Comment: Okay, great @furas. didn't realize that was what it was doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use module [jinja2](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/api/#basics) to use template with `for`-loops, `if/else`, etc.

`jinja2` is used by `Flask` to generate `HTML` but you could use it to generate any string - `HTML`, `XML`, `PDF`, `CSS`, `JS`, `CSV`, etc.

In example I uses `from_string()` but you can load template from file using `get_template()`.

```
from jinja2 import Environment

env = Environment()

text = '''
<tbody>
{% for r in tableRangeValues %}
<tr style="border-collapse:collapse; border:1px solid #000000">
    {% for value in r %}
     <td style="border-collapse:collapse; border:1px solid #000000">{{ value }}</td>
    {% endfor %}
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</tbody>
'''

#template = env.get_template("EmailTemplate")
template = env.from_string(text)

html = template.render(tableRangeValues=[[1,2,3], ["A","B","C"]])

print(html)
```

Result:

```
<tbody>

<tr style="border-collapse:collapse; border:1px solid #000000">
    
     <td style="border-collapse:collapse; border:1px solid #000000">1</td>
    
     <td style="border-collapse:collapse; border:1px solid #000000">2</td>
    
     <td style="border-collapse:collapse; border:1px solid #000000">3</td>
    
</tr>

<tr style="border-collapse:collapse; border:1px solid #000000">
    
     <td style="border-collapse:collapse; border:1px solid #000000">A</td>
    
     <td style="border-collapse:collapse; border:1px solid #000000">B</td>
    
     <td style="border-collapse:collapse; border:1px solid #000000">C</td>
    
</tr>

</tbody>
```

---

**EDIT:**

There are other `template engines`. See [template engines](https://www.fullstackpython.com/template-engines.html) on `Full Stack Python`.

Python has also standard `string.Template` or can use `string formatting` or `f-string` but it can't use `loops`, `if/else` inside template string.